# Python - Write json to BytesIO from dictionary object and store as compressed tar.gz

Tags: json, python-3.x, stream, tarfile, bytesio

My code is mostly working but I am having a bit of trouble writing a tar file to a remote filesystem. The code below is supposed to serialize a large dictionary to json and write to a compressed file object. The named temporary file is optional as I can write to a permanent file on the file system as well. fs is a gcsfs.GCSFileSystem object. It supports a put method for copying file to google cloud storage.

```
def write_main(fs, remote_fp, data):
    """
    input -
        fs filesystem object
        fp filepath or path object
        data object
    output - bool
    ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109180/dumping-json-directly-into-a-tarfile
    """
    tmp_file = NamedTemporaryFile()
    filename = tmp_file.name
    with io.BytesIO() as out_stream, tarfile.open(filename, 'w|gz', out_stream) as tar_file:
        out_stream.write(json.dumps(data).encode())
        tar_file.size = out_stream.tell()
        out_stream.seek(0)
        tar_file.addfile(tar_file, out_stream)

    fs.put(filename, remote_fp)
```

I get the following error when I try to test the function code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-020281a8b588> in <module>
      3     tar_file.size = out_stream.tell()
      4     out_stream.seek(0)
----> 5     tar_file.addfile(tar_file, out_stream)
      6
      7 fs.put(filename, remote_fp)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py in addfile(self, tarinfo, fileobj)
   1964         tarinfo = copy.copy(tarinfo)
   1965
-> 1966         buf = tarinfo.tobuf(self.format, self.encoding, self.errors)
   1967         self.fileobj.write(buf)
   1968         self.offset += len(buf)

AttributeError: 'TarFile' object has no attribute 'tobuf'
```

Answer (score 1):

@marian you were correct but I made one other mistake. Having passed out_stream to tarfile.open made the write fail for some reason. New code looks like this:

```
with io.BytesIO() as out_stream, tarfile.open(filename, 'w|gz') as tar_file:
    out_stream.write(json.dumps(data).encode())
    out_stream.seek(0)
    info = tarfile.TarInfo("data")
    info.size = len(out_stream.getbuffer())
    tar_file.addfile(info, out_stream)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you pass the wrong argument for tar_file. It should be a TarInfo object. That is why is raising the no attribute 'tobuf' error. [link](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/tarfile.py)

> ```
> def addfile(self, tarinfo, fileobj=None):
>     """Add the TarInfo object `tarinfo' to the archive. If `fileobj' is
>        given, tarinfo.size bytes are read from it and added to the archive.
>        You can create TarInfo objects using gettarinfo().
>        On Windows platforms, `fileobj' should always be opened with mode
>        'rb' to avoid irritation about the file size.
>     """
> ```